# using amazon s3 for a downloadable content website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm building a website which is simply a gallery of High resolution photos, and other downloadable contents (zip, rar, pdf ....), the user can upload files and those files are accessible and shareable by everyone.

My question: is amazon s3 good for this aspect? or should I use my own server. (There could be a huge amount of data shared across the web). I need your advice.

Thank you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon S3 is a great solution for downloadable content. Its highly available, already scaled to the max, extremely low maintenance and extremely well priced.

The simplest S3 solution for your use case would be:

1. create a bucket that will represent the storage location for your files that you want to be publicly accessible.
2. You need to upload a file that S3 will serve as a index document, I just upload a file called index.html that has the content of "hello".
3. Click on properties for the bucket
4. Expand the option "Static Website Hosting"
5. Select the option "Enable Website Hosting", enter the index.html as the index page and click Save. Once the save has taken place make a note of the "Endpoint" value displayed in this section, this is the DNS name for your bucket.
6. Click and expand the section "Permissions"
7. Click the "Add Bucket Policy" and add the policy I have pasted below, make sure you set your own buckets name where you see "my-bucket-name".

Bucket Policy:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Your bucket is now acting as static hosting and you have granted anonymous users the permissions needed to download content in the bucket.

Next upload whatever files you wish to make available in whatever key structure you see fit.

**Next Steps:**

Serving Paid / Private content

If you also want to host paid content you should check out serving private content using S3 and CloudFront. Here is some reading when you are ready to try this out!
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html

Customizing your DNS name for your static website

You can create a CNAME record in the zone file for a domain you own that points to your bucket making it less wordy and better branded for your site.
If you are using Route 53, create a new record set, set the type to "A" record, and select "Yes" for the option Alias Record, then paste the Endpoint name for your S3 Static Website into the value field to create your custom DNS record for your bucket.
Read more about Alias Records: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-alias.html#rrsets-values-alias-alias-target